# Auto update/fill a DATETIME column in MySQL using a trigger

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers

I'm trying to auto update/fill datetime columns in my database.

I'm current running:

MYSQL server: 5.1.56-log
MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.10

I've created two triggers based on the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

INSERT TRIGGER:

```
create trigger 'games_insert'
before insert
on games for each row

begin
set new.created = NOW();
set new.modified = NOW();
end;
```

MODIFICATION TRIGGER

```
create trigger 'games_update'
before update
on games for each row

begin
set new.modified = NOW();
end;
```

Both seem to be valid since you can only modify the new row prior to updating/inserting. The AFTER yields many more errors.

However, I keep getting the following syntax error and I'm not sure why:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
>   to use near ''games_insert' before insert on games for each row
>   begin set new.created =' at line 1

I'm interacting with the sql server through phpmyadmin and have set the delimiter to be $$

Answer (score 0):

don't use "'" in trigger name 
create trigger 'games_insert' (X)
create trigger games_insert (O)